# dbeaver Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

When trying to connect to mysql, i am getting this error: `Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'`.

I am able to connect fine from the terminal as well as mysql workbench.

mysql version is 8.0.20, dbeaver version is Version 7.3.2.202101032114.

```
2021-01-08 17:48:34.259 - Connection failed (mysql8-176e1ef2163-350bcdbb3d40cc61)
2021-01-08 17:48:34.260 - org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCConnectException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCConnectException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:222)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mysql.model.MySQLDataSource.openConnection(MySQLDataSource.java:419)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCExecutionContext.connect(JDBCExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.initializeMainContext(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:95)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.<init>(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:57)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.initializeRemoteInstance(JDBCDataSource.java:110)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.<init>(JDBCDataSource.java:98)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.<init>(JDBCDataSource.java:90)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mysql.model.MySQLDataSource.<init>(MySQLDataSource.java:90)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mysql.MySQLDataSourceProvider.openDataSource(MySQLDataSourceProvider.java:127)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry.DataSourceDescriptor.connect(DataSourceDescriptor.java:880)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectJob.run(ConnectJob.java:70)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectionTestJob.run(ConnectionTestJob.java:103)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.lambda$0(JDBCDataSource.java:177)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:196)
    ... 14 more
2021-01-08 17:48:34.318 - Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.lambda$0(JDBCDataSource.java:177)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:196)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mysql.model.MySQLDataSource.openConnection(MySQLDataSource.java:419)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCExecutionContext.connect(JDBCExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.initializeMainContext(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:95)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.<init>(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:57)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.initializeRemoteInstance(JDBCDataSource.java:110)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.<init>(JDBCDataSource.java:98)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.<init>(JDBCDataSource.java:90)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mysql.model.MySQLDataSource.<init>(MySQLDataSource.java:90)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mysql.MySQLDataSourceProvider.openDataSource(MySQLDataSourceProvider.java:127)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry.DataSourceDescriptor.connect(DataSourceDescriptor.java:880)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectJob.run(ConnectJob.java:70)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectionTestJob.run(ConnectionTestJob.java:103)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: [Options and Variables Removed in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/added-deprecated-removed.html#optvars-removed)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you know anything about why dbeaver is throwing this error?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue "Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'" for connecting to MySQL8 from dbeaver community version.  Tried all version of MySQL Java connector(mysql:mysql-connector-java) it didn't worked.  MariaDB driver in Dbeaver worked for me. Try **MariaDb driver to connect to MySQL8**. It will work.

```
<groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today while trying to connect to my local mysql database after a fresh install. Turns out there is mysql version mismatch. The 'MySql' option shown by default in the Popular tab is for Mysql version 4+. Which has an older connector attached to it. My locally installed MySql server version was 8.0.23. This combination does not work. In the new connection window, If you type mysql in the search box, it shows all the MySql versions [See attachment below- option 2 ]. From that I selected 'MySql 8+' and it prompted me to download the correct connector while creating a new connection. This worked without any trouble.

[image]

Comment: MySQL8+ is not listed for me in dbeaver

Comment: MySQL8+ is not listed for me either. What worked for me was using mariadb driver instead.

Comment: @RajeshM and Firoz: Are you sure you have selected the 'All" option in the list in the left hand side? (See my screen shot above) It will not show the options if 'Popular' is selected.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS Supported Community Version of dbeaver Version 21.0.5.202105160657 which released on 17 May 2021. Still this version doesn' t have MySQL 8+